# Ubuntu: Broadcast CNAMES/Alias to the router/ DHCP server/ DNS server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, hostname, hosts

I am trying to build a portable home server with a Intel NUC. My requirement is to plug my NUC to any of my friends or relatives router and with minimal configuration, preferably no configuration, be able to access docker services running on the server.

My current setup includes a plain ubuntu installation with services running as docker containers. I am using Traefik to expose my services and local network and donot need it to be available over internet. Only local network will do.

My issue now is, my DNS server at home, which is my Openwrt router have different CNAMES configured like nextcloud.home.lan -> home.lan(which is also configured to point to a static IP of my server). I obviously cannot expect to do these changes over my friends house.

So how I should go about achieving the desired results? I am open to suggestions using other software like maybe using Proxmox to run a DNS server(like PiHole) and then somehow virtually connect my other ubuntu VM this PiHole to passthrough internet and network access. IDK, I am newbie at this stuff.

I have observed that a hostname for ubuntu can be easily setup using the `hostname "new-hostname"` command. This is easily picked up by my dns server also. Can I do something similar to broadcast other alias hostnames to my server?

Comment: "docker services" is too vague. What services do you want to expose to the Internet? Identify which services need authenticated access (eg fileserver) and which are expected to be open (eg webserver). Is the question really "How can I have DNS names for my home system(s) that works for me when I'm elsewhere than at home?"

Comment: @roaima my docker services include media services like sonarr, and other utils nextcloud. Also using SAMBA server for sharing files.
My question is simple, how can I go about building a "plug and play" server, details mentioned in first paragraph. I am open to create my own network and wifi AP(using a switch and wifi card present in the nuc). All ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Nextcloud is intended to be safe for Internet access. Samba should not generally be exposed widely. DNS is usually hosted on a third party. I think your question is [too broad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to be answerable here

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to expose my services to internet. If the question is too broad, just give me a few ideas to look into, if you can think of something. I can try building solution from there.

Comment: If you don't want to expose your services to the Internet what's the relevance of "_My requirement is to go to any of my friends or relatives house and [...] be able to access docker services running on the server_"? Or do you simply mean you want to run a VPn service on your server so you can access it remotely?

Comment: Okay, now I see. My apologies. I see how I have written an ambiguous statement. Let me edit that. What I want is to take my server which is a Intel NUC mini and plug into my friends router and have access to it locally.